# My Rails app returns 500, but I can't see any details in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**curl localhost:3000/groups** gives

```
Started GET "/groups" for 193.160.199.32 at 2018-07-05 13:41:04 +0000
Processing by GroupsController#index as */*
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 94ms (Views: 0.1ms)
```

But why can't I see any more details?

I've set `RAILS_ENV=staging`

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.env
=> "staging"
```

**grep log config/environments/staging.rb**

```
  config.log_level = :debug
  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Comment: Where does `:authenticate_user` come from?

Comment: **$ ack authenticate_user**
`app/controllers/application_controller.rb
8:  before_action :prepare_vega_auth, :authenticate_user, :set_notification
55:  def authenticate_user`

Comment: And what's the content of `authenticate_user` method ?